# How to make a keypress form event in C#

Tags: c#, keyboard-events

I'm trying to make a KeyPress event on a form, but in this line I got an error `MainWindow.KeyPress = new KeyPressEventArgs(Form_KeyPress);`, I read the Microsoft Docs about events in C#, but I don't get the idea.

Do listeners like in Java exist in C# or not?

My code:

```cs
class PracticeEvent
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Form MainWindow = new Form();
        MainWindow.Text = "Practice";
        MainWindow.MaximizeBox = false;
        MainWindow.MinimizeBox = false;
        MainWindow.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        MainWindow.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        MainWindow.Size = new Size(1000, 700);
        MainWindow.KeyPreview = true;
        MainWindow.KeyPress = new KeyPressEventArgs(Form_KeyPress); 

        MainWindow.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void Form_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.A){
            MessageBox.Show("You pressed the A key.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are getting an error, paste it in your question. And if you want clarification of an idea, you need to explain what part doesn't make sense.  Otherwise you'll just get rewordings of the thing you read and didn't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several errors in your code.

`MainWindow.KeyPress = new KeyPressEventArgs(Form_KeyPress);`

1) `KeyPress` has `KeyPressEventHandler` type. Not `KeyPressEventArgs`. In C# classes which called `...EventArgs` are usually used as special objects that contains data about a raised event and them are inherited from `EventArgs` system class. And classes which called `...EventHandlers` are usually define wrapper for delegates and called events.

2) So `KeyPress` is event. If you want to subscribe this event you should use `+=` operator. And method that you want to specify as handler should have signature `void(object, KeyPressEventArgs)`. Typical signature for events is `void(object, ...EventArgs)`

`private void Form_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)`

3) As I said this method has wrong signature (`KeyPressEventArgs` instead `KeyEventArgs`).

4) It should be `static`. You can not use non-static class members in static method.

So your code should look like this:

```
    class PracticeEvent
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            Form MainWindow = new Form();
            MainWindow.Text = "Practice";
            MainWindow.MaximizeBox = false;
            MainWindow.MinimizeBox = false;
            MainWindow.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            MainWindow.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            MainWindow.Size = new Size(1000, 700);
            MainWindow.KeyPreview = true;
            MainWindow.KeyPress += Form_KeyPress;
            MainWindow.ShowDialog();
        }

        private static void Form_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 'a')
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You pressed the A key.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Use listeners in C# is not good practice, but some frameworks use it. Usually events and callbacks is used.

And my last advice. May be you want to use the `KeyDown` event? The `KeyPress` is used for working with char input.

Comment: It works!, thank you!, i will read more about EventArgs and EventHandler in the microsoft docs.

Answer (score 2):

Your main method is static, your event handler is not. You need to provide it an object reference, that's what the error message is trying to say. Another error is that you are assigning rather than attaching the handler, use `+=` operator for that.

Specifically, change this line:

`MainWindow.KeyPress = new KeyPressEventArgs(Form_KeyPress);`

to be

```
var instance = new PracticeEvent();
MainWindow.KeyPress += instance.Form_KeyPress;
```

Comment: Two bugs, use += to subscribe an event.

Comment: My bad! Missed that bit.

Comment: It is still wrong, the delegate type is KeyEventHandler.  Probably best to recommend the syntax sugar version: MainWindow.KeyPress += instance.Form_KeyPress;

Comment: And the other one too. That's what I get when I am writing impromptu code in the answer itself.